# MVC4 Selecting from a List of Items in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I'm looking for a way to select from a lists of items that I have retrieve from a database. I send these items to a view and I want to select from the list and return this to the controller to populate a secondary table within the database. I can pass the items to the view and get them to display but I can not seem to pass these items back to the controller.

Controller Calls (Updated Again):

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var myMeal = new CreateMeal();
        List<ProductsToInclude> pti = new List<ProductsToInclude>();
        myMeal.ProductsToInclude = pti;
        IList<Product> prods = db.Products.ToList();


        foreach(var prod in prods)
        {
            pti.Add(new ProductsToInclude { Product = prod });
        }

        return View(myMeal);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Meal/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateMeal myMeal)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            /* Add code to handle my meal and create a meal for data base*/
            db.Meals.Add(meal);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pti);
    }
```

The ProductsToInclude ViewModel

```
public class ProductsToInclude
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Boolean Include { get; set; }
}
```

New CreateMeal ViewModel:

```
public class CreateMeal
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductsToInclude> ProductsToInclude { get; set; }
}
```

The Create View:

```
@model MealPlanner.ViewModels.CreateMeal

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Meal</legend>

        <div>
          @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductsToInclude)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And the Editor Templete (UpDated) :

```
@model MealPlanner.ViewModels.ProductsToInclude

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Include)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Product.Name 
        @Model.Product.Quantity 
        @Model.Product.unit.UnitName
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Product.Name) 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Product.Quantity) 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Product.unit.UnitName)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Meal Model:

```
public class Meal
{
    public int MealId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    //public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:

Switching over to EditorTemplete I can not get this to display. I get an error now with myMeal.ProductsToInclude.Add(new ProductsToInclude { Product = prod, Include = false}); in the Create Method. prod is populated has 8 products in it.

Comment: I see potential error that's most likely the issue, but to give you a full answer can you update your question with the code for Meal class?

Comment: Have you checked the Request's form data in the post back?  Has it got what you need in there just named differently to what you would expect?

Comment: @PeteGO Return form data is null

Comment: saying "I get an error" and then not including that error is rather pointless.

Comment: @Mystere Man - sorry was in the middle of edits. I get an error creating when trying myMeal.ProductsToInclude.Add(new ProductsToInclude { Product = prod, Include = false}); in the Create Method

Comment: The error you get is probably a null reference exception, because you are not creating a List object, you are only defining one.  You need to initialize it with a new List object.

Comment: @Mystere Man - It is but I've tried several different ways to create a new item and still get the null pointer exception. Example Please!

Comment: @jbolt - you are not listening.  It's not the new item that's the problem.  It's the list property you are calling .Add() on.  You are defining CreateMeal with an IList, but you do not create an actual new List object to assign it to.

Comment: Sometimes you look at code for so long that it just doesn't make any sense anymore. Thank you @MystereMan for your help. Updating code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two basic problems here. (and a third, you're not passing any model to the view, but your view is expecting a Meal object)  First, is that you are posting a different model than you are rendering from.  So, when you post your form it's not going to recognize the Meal.Name object because the post action is expecting a list of ProductsToInclude.

If you don't intend to change the value of the Meal.Name, then I would suggest rendering it with a DisplayFor rather than an EditorFor.

Second, the way you are rendering your form fields will not create the correct naming structure to allow the default model binder to bind to the collections.  You can use EditorTemplates, which is the method I prefer.

Instead of using the Partial, you would create an editor template called ProductsToInclude.cshtml, set the model type to be ProductsToInclude (without the List) and then render as if it were a single item.  You will also want to move the table and header info out into the main view.

EditorTemplates handle this situation without having to do anything special.  They automatically iterate over collections, and they render names correctly.  Use them wherever you can.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Include")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Available Products")
            </th>
            <th></th>
       </tr>
       @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductsToInclude)
    </table>
</div>
```

Your ProductsToInclude.cshtml should live in a folder called EditorTemplates in either ~/Views/Shared or in your local view folder.

```
@model ProductsToInclude
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Include)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Product.Name) 
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Product.Quantity) 
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Product.unit.UnitName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.PrimaryKey }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=Model.PrimaryKey }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=Model.PrimaryKey })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In the example you have @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductsToInclude): what model would I be sending into the Create Method? Would that be a list of ProductsToInclude (pti?). The MealName is there for the user to name the meal they are creating. Essentially I need to be able to create a meal based off of products that were previously created. How I get there is my stumbling block.

Comment: @jbolt - You're going to have to figure that out.  You shouldn't be passing ProductsToInclude in ViewBag, but rather as a part of your view model, which should also contain the Name property.  Essentialy your view model should contain all the information your view needs.  You pass that view model to the view as a parameter of the `View()` method you return form your controller action.

Comment: Updated code base (see update). This I took from an example [Editor Templetes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073088/return-listt-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc-3).