# how to get binded list in [HttpPost] action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strongly typed view and its model is a list. I m wondering why I cannot get model back in controller action?

Placing a break point I observed on form submitting  control comes to action but list is null.

Below is my view:

```
@model List<BL.Model.Speaker>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
            @{
    foreach (var speaker in Model)
    { 
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(s => speaker.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(s => speaker.Email)</td>

                </tr>
    }
           }            
    </table>
    @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "All");
}
```

My controller action is as below:

```
public ActionResult All(List<Speaker> model)
        {
            List<Speaker> speakers = database.Speakers.ToList();

            return View(speakers);


        }
```

MVC champs please help me. What I want to do is after editing, want to see updated values on my post action.

Much appriciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073088/return-listt-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc-3/12073450#12073450

Comment: @Chris Pratt, it is not duplicate, in this question I have asked returning a list from view but in other it is a simple object.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, this question was asked BEFORE the other question. The other question should be the duplicated one. This cannot be duplicated if it was asked first.

Comment: Whoever marked this question as duplicated, please make sure the time order is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Speaker list ViewModel, then use for instead of using foreach in your view using the ViewModel, like below:

**ViewModel**

```
public class SpeakerViewModel
{
    public List<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; } 
}
```

**View**

```
@model  Demo.Models.SpeakerViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Speakers.Count; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Speakers[i].Name)</td>

            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Speakers[i].Email)</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

**Action**

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult All()
    {
        var model = new SpeakerViewModel()
        {
            Speakers = database.Speakers.ToList();
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult All(SpeakerViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I m not able to get model back in action on post which is List<Speaker>. What changing loop will effect on it ?

Comment: hi @haansi, to explain why instead of using foreach, you should use for, see this link, it's a good reference. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx